# Creating a timer with UIViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, timer

I am working on an timer app. As seen here [Timer App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AePEa.png). This timer app works with a custom UIView Cell. Everything was working fine until you create more timers (cells) than what are displayed. For example, say that I added 15 timers, which 10 are displayed (Shown on screen), and 5 are not. If I start one of the timers on display, and then scroll down to reveal the rest of the timers, you will see that one of them is already running without manually starting it. It seems as if it's replicated. I do know that the system reuses the cells. How can I avoid that ? How can I make it so that the timers work individually regardless of how many there are ?

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG9h9.jpg)

```
TimerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UITextFieldDelegate {

// MARK: - Properties
var time = 30
var displayTime = 30
var counterRun = NSTimer()
var startTime = NSTimeInterval()
var currentTime = NSTimeInterval()

@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var startLabel: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var numberText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonImage: UIButton!

// MARK: - Defaults
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    /// Initialization code
    numberText.delegate = self

}
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    /// Configure the view for the selected state
}

// MARK: Delegate Function

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    /// Hide the keyboard
    numberText.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func startButton(sender: UIButton) {
    /// Makes time run
    if displayTime == 0 {
        time = 30
        displayTime = 30
        timeLabel.text = "\(displayTime)"
        counterRun = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timeRunner", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        startLabel.selected = true
        startLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "Stop"), forState: .Selected)
    }
    else if startLabel.selected == true {
        startLabel.selected = false
        startLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "Start"), forState: .Normal)
        counterRun.invalidate()
        time = displayTime
    }
    else {
        startLabel.selected = true
        startLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "Stop"), forState: .Selected)
        counterRun = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timeRunner", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    }
}

func timeRunner(){
    currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    let elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime
    ///calculate the minutes in elapsed time.
    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 1)
    let minutesInt = Int(minutes)
    displayTime = time - minutesInt
    timeLabel.text = "\(displayTime)"

    timeStopper()
}

func timeStopper(){
    if displayTime <= 0 {
        startLabel.selected = false
        startLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "Start"), forState: .Normal)
        counterRun.invalidate()
    }
}

@IBAction func refreshButton(sender: UIButton) {
    startLabel.selected = false
    startLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "Start"), forState: .Normal)
    time = 30
    displayTime = 30
    timeLabel.text = "\(displayTime)"
    counterRun.invalidate()
}

@IBAction func changePhoto(sender: UIButton) {
    let duckPhoto = UIImage(named: "Duck")
    let swanPhoto = UIImage(named: "Swan")

    /// Changes the photo of the cell.
    if buttonImage.selected == false {
        buttonImage.selected = true
        buttonImage.setImage(swanPhoto, forState: .Selected)
    }
    else if buttonImage.selected == true {
        buttonImage.selected = false
        buttonImage.setImage(duckPhoto, forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

}

Here is the UITableViewController

```
class TimerTableViewController: UITableViewController {


// MARK: - Properties

var timers = [Time]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    /// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    /// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    /// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    /// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return timers.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "TimerCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell

    let time = timers[indexPath.row]

    cell.timeLabel.text = "\(time.time)"
    cell.buttonImage.setImage(time.photo, forState: .Normal)
    return cell
}



/// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    /// Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}



/// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        /// Delete the row from the data source
        timers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        /// Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}

/// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

/// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    /// Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}


// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func addButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let photo = UIImage(named: "Duck")
    let time = Time(time: 30, photo: photo!)

    let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: timers.count, inSection: 0)
    timers.append(time)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)

}
```

}

And the class to make the timer objects

```
class Time {
let time: Int
let photo: UIImage

init(time: Int, photo: UIImage){
    self.time = time
    self.photo = photo
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are making beginners mistakes with cells and cell re-use. It also isn't at all clear what you are doing with timers. Are you talking about `NSTimer`s? Do you create one for each cell? What do they do? What method do they invoke, and what do you mean when you say a timer "is displayed?" Post the relevant parts of your code or we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I am sure I am making beginners mistakes all over. "is displayed" meaning that it's showing on screen. No I don't create one for each cell. I will update my question and add the code. Thanks for replying ! Looking forward to a helpful answer !

Comment: @DuncanC I just added the code. Thanks

Comment: Ok, you've posted the code for your custom UITableViewCell subclass. Now how about the code for your table view data source methods?(cellForRowAtIndexPath, etc.)

Comment: @DuncanC There, I've added everything I have.

Comment: @DuncanC Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overriding the reuse behavior of the table view cells, as I originally answered, it is better that you work with it. The reason is that this is something you will need to frequently use in apps and it also conforms to the MVC paradigm used predominantly in iOS.

The table cells are meant to only be a **view** and, therefore, independent from your **model** in the MVC paradigm.

Your views, the table view cells, are reused for reasons of efficiency and this is beneficial for everyone.

You have your timers in an an array and that represents your model. You are updating the views from your model in your controller using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and this is great except for one thing.

The mistake that you are making is you are storing model data in your table view cell view, `TimerTableViewCell`, that should instead be limited to rendering the data in your model. By storing model data in your view you are running into the problem of the model data not being correct when the views are reused.

The `NSTimer` needs to be moved from your cell view to your `Time` class for it to be independent of your views. It will then be an instance member when you create new `Time` objects. Your array of `Time` objects will then hold independently running timers as you create new ones.

Once the timers are separated from the view, you will not have the problem of the model data getting mixed up when the views are recycled through `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

The challenge with the reuseable cells will then be to make sure that the cell is displaying the correct model data everytime it is reused. A cell can be momentarily visible before the new cell is fully rendered and you may need to hide a new cell temporarily until the data has been fully updated.

This may not be the quick solution that you may have been looking for, but it will help you greatly with implementing MVC.

Comment: That does not seem to work, it gives me an error when I try to add a new timer ! :( Any other suggestions ?

Comment: When I press the add button the app crashes and says found nil, when trying to unwrap an optional. And it takes me to this line.      cell.timeLabel.text = "\(time.time)"

Comment: I've updated my answer to retrieve your cell from a XIB file if that is how you have the view of your cell defined.

Comment: Thanks, will check if that works, getting on an aircraft right now, will let you know as soon as possible. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem, Jhoan. The answer is for having your table view cell in `TimerCell.xib`.  I hope that will work for your app.

Comment: I changed that part of the code and it gave me an even bigger error, but now that I read your last comment perhaps I'm not doing something right. Please bare with me, I'm new to coding and obviously making beginners errors. This will be my first app that works with uitableviews. I don't think I have TimerCell.xib.

Comment: If your table view cell is not a separate xib and a prototype cell in your storyboard, I've added a solution for that case. Otherwise, please post a screenshot of how you have your cell defined in Interface Builder so that I might help you further.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to my question. "Storyboard cell screenshot". I did change my code to your last suggestion and that also gave me an error. Thanks for helping me out, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: I understand it can be frustrating. The screenshot really helps. What error do you get now?

Comment: I changed the screenshot, perhaps I can give you my e-mail or something, I feel like this thing does not want me to extend discussions in comments lol ! jhoannarango@msn.com